# Why do I get connection refused when I telnet port 2194?

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, telnet, ufw, port

I'm setting up an OpenVPN access server and I continuously get the error "connection refused" on my client(s). So i decided to start debugging from the beginning (the server) and tried `telnet 127.0.0.1 2194`. The result:

```
openvpn_as_test_1:~$ telnet 127.0.0.1 2194
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

So this means the issue is on the server so I checked if the port is open in `ufw` with `sudo ufw status` and noticed the port was not allowed by the firewall. After adding the port with `ufw allow 2194/udp` (and `ufw allow 2194/tcp` even when this is needed). After checking `ufw status` again, this was the result:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
2194/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
2194/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
2194/udp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
2194/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

The port is allowed by the internal firewall so i tried `telnet 127.0.0.1 2194` again and guess what, still `connection refused`:

```
openvpn_as_test_1:~$ telnet 127.0.0.1 2194
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Ok, what else could be te problem? maybe telnet does not work properly so i tried `telnet 127.0.0.1 22`:

```
openvpn_as_test_1:~$ telnet 127.0.0.1 22
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
```

Great, telnet is working fine so.. lets check netstat to see if we listen to port 2194:

```
openvpn_as_test_1:~$ netstat -al | grep "LISTEN"
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:943             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:https           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:904           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:905           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:906           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:907           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:908           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:909           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     13660    /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22260    /run/user/1000/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22264    /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22265    /run/user/1000/snapd-session-agent.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22266    /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.dirmngr
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22267    /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.extra
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22268    /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.browser
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     22269    /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13568    /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13578    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16810    /run/uuidd/request
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16816    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16828    /run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16830    /run/snapd.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16832    /run/snapd-snap.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13662    /run/lvm/lvmpolld.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     13839    /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16861    /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20300    /usr/local/openvpn_as/etc/sock/sagent
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20303    /usr/local/openvpn_as/etc/sock/sagent.localroot
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20304    /usr/local/openvpn_as/etc/sock/sagent.api
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16865    @ISCSIADM_ABSTRACT_NAMESPACE
```

Port 2194 is not listed here. Ok, now I have no idea how to continue. Where is my issue?

Comment: Is the daemon that is providing your service on port 2194 actually running? Is it a TCP service or an UDP service?

Comment: I'm new to OpenVPN Access Server and i cannot find anything how i can check if the server is running on that port. I assume it does as i configured this port in the admin interface. It should be an UDP service. --- Tomorrow i will continue testing and try to figure out if there is a way to test if the service really uses 2194 as my assumption may be tricky

Comment: `Connection refused` means either your firewall refused it or there is no listener.  According to the output of netstat, there is no listener.  So, the service is either not running or you confuse it with another port number that is actually listed.

Comment: For some reason `telnet 127.0.0.1 2194` says that the connection is refused but i got OpenVPN AS working now via that port. So problem is solved (added a missing route in firewall) but does still not explain why telnet on localhost does refuse connection but doesn't matter anymore now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have allowed the wrong port on `ufw`: you're trying to use port 2194 for telnet and you've allowed port 1194 according to the output of `ufw show status` you posted.

Comment: OMG, how stupid! I added the correct port but this still results in the same issue. I updated my question as well.